# JQuery Autocomplete and grabbing extra data from JSON feed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following jquery which reads from the excellent geonames.org web service:

```
$('#<%=txtFindMyCity.ClientID%>').autocomplete("http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON", {
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            parse: function (data) {
                var rows = new Array();
                data = data.geonames;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    rows[i] = { data: data[i], value: data[i].name, result: data[i].name };
                }
                return rows;
            },
            formatItem: function (row, i, n) {
                $('#lat').val(row.lat); //<---- THIS
                $('#lon').val(row.lng); //<---- AND THIS
                return row.name + ', ' + row.adminName1 + ' ' + row.adminName2 + ' ' + row.adminName3 + row.lat + row.lng;
            },
            extraParams: {
                // geonames doesn't support q and limit, which are the autocomplete plugin defaults, so let's blank them out.
                q: '',
                limit: '',
                country: '<%=Session["BusinessCountry"].ToString()%>',
                featureClass: 'P',
                style: 'full',
                maxRows: 50,
                name_startsWith: function () {
                    return $('#<%=txtFindMyCity.ClientID%>').val()
                }
            },
            max: 50
        }).result(function (event, data, formatted) {
            var selectedcity = $('#<%=txtFindMyCity.ClientID%>').val();
            $('#citymap').show('slow');
            $('#resultsmap').googleMaps({
                latitude: $('#lat').val(),
                longitude: $('#lon').val(),
                controls: {
                    type: {
                        control: ''
                    },
                    zoom: {
                        control: 'GSmallZoomControl'
                    }
                }
                //geocode: selectedcity + ' <%=ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text%>',
            });

        });
```

The issue I am having is that, I want the data marked.  The service returns lat and lon as you can see from within `formatItem`, but I have no idea how to get it. I tried setting the values of an input - this kind of worked - but it only got the first in the datafeed, not the selected.  I have the `result(function(event, data, formatted)` method, but `data` or `data[0|1]` never returns anything.

I'm at a loss! Any help anyone can provide would be awesomes :)

Comment: Not entirely clear on what the problem is. Have you tried using `console.log()` or similar to see what `row` is in your `formatItem()` function?

Comment: Thanks for the response no.good.at.coding :)

Comment: Whoops, pressed return... The problem is I want to be able to save `row.lat` and `row.lng` when they are selected. Otherwise I just have text for the selected city - which is meaningless when there are plenty of cities with the same name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think now I see what you're trying to do and perhaps how you can do it. You want to access the values for `lat` and `lng` along with `name` for an item when it is selected (which is what the `result` function is meant to do).

This should work:

```
$('#<%=txtFindMyCity.ClientID%>').autocomplete("http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON", {
        //all your existing options go here
    }).result(function (event, data, formatted) {
            //access the lat, lng and name of the selected option:
            console.log("You selected ", data.name, data.lat, data.lng);
        });

    });
```

Comment: no.good.at.coding, spot on! absolutely perfect, thanks very much :) +1